# Why is it okay to not capture return value in Java?

Tags: java, return, stringbuilder

I have written small code.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("Hello");
System.out.println(sb);
```

The definition of method says that return type is StringBuilder.

```
public StringBuilder append(String str)
```

Why is it not giving error?

Thank you.

Comment: `StringBuilder` uses the builder pattern and is generally implemented to allow you to perform method chaining, so you could do `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().append("Hello");` and that would legal.  Don't get confused with non-mutable classes like `LocalDateTime`, which you MUST assign the result of a "mutable" action (like `plus`), which leaves the original instance unchanged and returns a new instance with the modifications applied.  `StringBuilder` is mutable, but provides convenience.  You are also quite free to ignore the result of any method you like

Answer (score 3):

Because it is not required to save the value in to a local reference. In fact, most methods of `StringBuilder` return a `StringBuilder` so that calls can be chained.

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.append("Hello, World"); // <-- also returns the StringBuilder
 System.out.println(sb);
```

Comment: Can it be generalized ? I wrote a method which returned int. But, I didn't save it..

Comment: @JayPatel You need to know the difference between a mutable and non-mutable state.  `StringBuilder` is mutable, which means, when you call `append`, it's internal state is updated and the same instance of `StringBuilder` is returned, this is done for convenience and makes it easier to work with (as you don't need to keep typing `sb.append(...)` over and over again).  Something like `LocalDate`, for example, is not mutable, when you call one of it's mutators, it returns a NEW instance of the object with the modifications applied, leaving the original instance unchanged.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you.. I got it.